# Unity 2D side scrolling game stutter/jerk/lag issue when run on iOS devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile, unity3d-2dtools

I just want to say thanks in advance for anyone you can provide some help on this we're completely stuck at the moment.

Project Scenario : -> 2D side scrolling game with simple 2d sprites -> Camera is orthographic and stays in its place (camera doesn't move) -> My Character (A camel) is also static and does not move. -> The sprites (Platforms) move from right to left (movement done by script) -> Project Video is uploaded here (running on iphone5). It clearly shows the small hiccups and jerks.

Issue : The game works very smoothly on Android devices and Unity Editor (no spikes on the Unity profiler as well) But, when i run it on iOS devices (iphone5, iphon5s) the motion of my sprites is jerky. Like it will move smoothly for like 1 second and then a small hiccup/jerk of a split second occurs. This results in lag and lagging motion of the game which is very annoying as i am unable to get the right quality for iOS.

Things i have tried : -> I have studied many possible solutions on various threads and forums but none issue seems to be working for me :-( -> I have tried different scripting techniques like use Lerp function for movement, tried putting the code in LateUpdate and also FixedUpdate. -> I also turned off vSync in project Quality settings but no luck :-( -> I also tried the movement without the script by making an animation of the sprites to move from right to left. -> I tried making the project from the latest Unity 5.1 as well but still the same lag :-( -> I tried reducing the sprite sizes to very low (low quality pixels) but still issue prevailed. -> I also tried to change the camera to perspective view to see if it reduces the jerk or not

I am sure lots of other people around must have faced this issue while making a 2D game of such sort. I hope someone must have overcome the issue and can please help me with this. This has been an issue with me for long now ...

I would really appreciate any help ... any new technique in unity or any better optimised logic of making such a 2D game in Unity. Thanks.

Looking forward to everyones input.

YOUTUBE LINK TO VIDEO FOR REFERENCE - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnST1QzoDw4

Comment: Hi, some ideas..:
Have you tried profiling? 
Maybe it can be a way to know which process is consuming more resources and see if the cause of your problem could be a code issue.
Are you using pooling? Are you resusing your scenario elements? Sometimes creating and destroying objects causes little lags.

Comment: I have same issue, even my game is more simple than yours, just 1 sprite for background and 1 sprite renderer for moving object. I switch the Vsync on and off but it not work. I think this is Unity problem.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that project? Or at least the code for the moving object?

Comment: Hi,did you find the solution? It would be appreciated if you can help